# Error Application terminated when I install it on my device

Tags: android, android-studio

App works fine on AVD but when I install it on my physical device, it breaks down with this error:

> I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13536 SIG: 9
>   Application terminated.

Comment: Have you tried investigating? Have you found any clues? Any potential bits of code that may be the culprit?